# How to add SQL user-defined function to entity framework?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-4

Can I add a SQL function to my .edmx file like I do in .dbml? If I can, how to do that? If I can not, is there any workaround?

I tried to Google but can't find any concrete answer about how to do that.

Based on the given answer I have created a Stored procedure and tried to add a 'import function', but it says **'the stored procedure returns no column'** . Where am I doing wrong?
The function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_locationSearch](@keyword varchar(10))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
SELECT CustomerBranch.ID,CustomerBranch.BranchName,CustomerBranch.Longitude,CustomerBranch.Latitue,CustomerBranch.Telephone,CustomerBranch.CategoryID,CustomerBranch.Description

FROM FREETEXTTABLE (CustomerOffer,*,@keyword) abc INNER JOIN OffersInBranch
ON abc.[key]=OffersInBranch.OfferID INNER JOIN CustomerBranch ON     OffersInBranch.BranchID=CustomerBranch.ID
UNION
SELECT    CustomerBranch.ID,CustomerBranch.BranchName,CustomerBranch.Longitude,CustomerBranch.Latitude,CustomerBranch.Telephone,CustomerBranch.CategoryID,CustomerBranch.Description
FROM CustomerBranch WHERE FREETEXT(*,@keyword)
)
```

The Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE USP_locationSearch
(@keyword varchar(10))
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * from dbo.fn_locationSearch(@keyword)
END
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no built in support for SQL User Defined Functions in Entity Framework, your best approach would be to create a stored procedure which wraps the function call and returns its output, then add that procedure to your EF model.

Comment: Thanks. In that case will I be able to write query, like var result=from p in dc.mytable join q in dc.myUSPwithFunc('id') ...??

Comment: Yes, when you add your stored procedure you will need to add a function import and the return type will be a complex type, the EF designer has the ability to generate a new complex type for you. The 'complex type' is really a new class that is based on the fields returned by your procedure.

Comment: Hi. I am just not getting through. :( I have edited my post and added the code i am trying to write as per your answer. Can you plz have a look?

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue.
What I did is ,I put the result of my Stored procedure into a Table variable and select from there.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[USP_locationSearch]
(@keyword varchar(10))
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @locationtable TABLE
(
ID int,
BranchName varchar(150),
Longitude varchar(150),
Latitude varchar(150),
Telephone varchar(50),
CategoryID int,
Description varchar(500)
)
INSERT INTO @locationtable SELECT * from dbo.fn_locationSearch(@keyword)
SELECT * FROM @locationtable
END
```

Then refresh the stored procedure in the entity framework. Then add 'function input'. everything went cool.

more details on this issue can be found [here](http://mysoftwarenotes.wordpress.com/2010/11/02/entity-framework-4-the-selected-stored-procedure-returns-no-columns/)