# How can I call SQL Server database function from MVC3 controller?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use SQL user defined functions in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056390/how-to-use-sql-user-defined-functions-in-net)

Say I have created a SQL Server function `function1(int a,int b)` in my database, now how can I call this function in MVC3 controller ?

Comment: I think you should do that in model, not in controller. Model consists of application data and the controller mediates input, converting it to commands for the model or view.

Comment: Pabloker is correct.  You call the function in your SQL. And your SQL comprises the model.

Answer (score 0):

You would use either [ADO.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h43ks021%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or any one of many other database technologies.

Comment: Then you want to [do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051299/how-to-add-sql-user-defined-function-to-entity-framework)