# How to add function to edmx

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I need help using functions using Entity framework.

I have table valued function in databse on SQL server.

I am trying to add the function into edmx, but id does not show me that function.
It shows only stored procedure, but no functions when I click on Update model from database.

How can I import or use the functions using EF ?

Comment: Which version of Entity Framework are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Answer to your Question is already in [StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8051299/how-to-add-sql-user-defined-function-to-entity-framework)

> There is no built in support for SQL User Defined Functions in Entity
>   Framework, your best approach would be to create a stored procedure
>   which wraps the function call and returns its output, then add that
>   procedure to your EF model.

Comment: Table Valued Functions are supported in EF5 (.NET Framework 4.5) and EF6 (.NET Framework 4 and .NET Framework 4.5) if you are using edmx.